# UWP .NET Native - Iterate Through Types and Assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types, .net-native

We need to iterate over all assemblies in our app, and then get types that have a CustomAttribute of type DataContract. This is the code that currently works in UWP when not compiled for .NET Native:

```
    public async Task Initialise()
    {

        var files = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFilesAsync();
        if (files == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        _Assemblies = new List<Assembly>();

        foreach (var file in files.Where
            (
                file => (file.FileType.ToLower() == ".dll" || file.FileType == ".exe") &&
                !new List<string> { "clrjit", "clrcompression", "sqlite3", "ucrtbased" }.Contains(file.DisplayName)
            ))
        {
            try
            {
                _Assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(file.DisplayName)));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        _Types = _Assemblies.SelectMany
           (
           a => a.GetTypes().Where
               (
                   t => t.GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttribute<DataContractAttribute>() != null ||
                   t.GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttribute<CollectionDataContractAttribute>() != null
               )
           ).ToList();
    }
```

This fails when compiling for .NET Native toolchain. Firstly, we only see one assembly which is an exe, and that has no types in it.

**What do we need to change? How do we get the assemblies and their types?**

Note: What we really need is a definitive list of reflection APIs that are supported by .NET Native and those that aren't.

Comment: Well, that was a bad idea.  It doesn't have anything to do with api support, the .NET Native compiler is simply very aggressive about removing types that don't seem to be used to make the smallest possible executable.  Reflection is a problem, reflected type names are not explicit in the code.  Since it can't find any reference in the code to those attributed types it is not going to include them.  You have to add them by hand to the rd.xml file.  All the docs about .NET Native talk about this.

Comment: This isn't helpful at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the main difference between standard UWP, and .NET Native is that all of the assemblies are compiled in to machine code, and probably sit inside the exe rather than .NET Assembly DLLs, so the above code no longer works. However, the method is still the same so long as you actually know which assemblies are being used. In this case I have hard coded the assemblies, but I could potentially use the Assembly.Load method to dynamically load assemblies at runtime. However, I'm not sure if the store validator will allow this code. I may have to ask a separate question if the validator rejects this code.

```
    #region Public Methods

    public async Task Initialise()
    {
        _Assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
        _Assemblies.Add(typeof(ReflectionUtils).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
        _Assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("Adapt.Model.Helpdesk")));
        _Assemblies.Add(typeof(SavePage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
        _Assemblies.Add(typeof(XivicClient.WCF.ServiceCalls.GeneralCalls).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

        _Types = _Assemblies.SelectMany
           (
           a => a.GetTypes().Where
               (
                   t => t.GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttribute<DataContractAttribute>() != null ||
                   t.GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttribute<CollectionDataContractAttribute>() != null
               )
           ).ToList();
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: I will mark this as the answer once I've been able to successfully get this in to the Store.

Comment: This code works, and has been successfully been validated by the Microsoft store.